# Late running Eurostar service from Brussels

Tags: trains

What happens if my Eurostar service from Brussels is running late and I miss my Grand Central train from Kings Cross

Comment: Please elaborate your question, what exactly are you asking? You will miss your train, that is what happens.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your train ticket from Kings Cross.

In the UK, there is a special train station called London International (CIV) and London Eurostar (CIV).  If you book a domestic train ticket from this station, then any connection with an international train is guaranteed under CIV rights.  That means that if you travel to London and miss the Eurostar, you are entitled to take a later Eurostar, and to hotel accommodation if the later Eurostar is tomorrow.  Conversely, if you travel to London and miss your UK domestic train, you are entitled to take the next one and, if applicable, get hotel accommodation or a taxi if you missed the last train.

International trains means either the Eurostar or the train+ferry to Harwich-Hoek van Holland.

For more information, see the [UK connections](https://www.seat61.com/UKconnections.htm) page on Seat61.

See also: *[What happens if I miss my Eurostar because of a delay in a domestic train to get to it?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13181/2509)*

Comment: Even without a CIV ticket (which is almost certainly the case), it is policy that in case of a missed connection due to any train delay then the traveller can travel on the next service.

Comment: @MarkPerryman In practice, yes. With a CIV ticket, it's a right. Flexible CIV tickets are also sometimes cheaper than full-flex tickets to places not very close to London, so I would recommend to try getting a CIV ticket anyway.

Comment: The Eurostar and UK tickets have been booked seperately. My journey from Kings Cross is to Sunderland by Open Access operator Grand Central. As there is only an hour between connections and the G.C. service is their last of the day would I be able to use an LNER service via Newcastle. (or could I buy a LNER ticket and claim back the cost from Eurostar)

Answer (score 0):

Get a note made on your Eurostar ticket by the train manager and then get on the next available service from Kings Cross. You will be allowed to travel (though will not have a reserved seat).

Comment: The Eurostar and UK tickets have been booked seperately. My journey from Kings Cross is to Sunderland by Open Access operator Grand Central. As there is only an hour between connections and the G.C. service is their last of the day would I be able to use an LNER service via Newcastle. (or could I buy a LNER ticket and claim back the cost from Eurostar)

Comment: You should talk to the Eurostar train manager on the train, and then to the staff at Kings Cross. The general rule is that you would be allowed to travel onwards, but Eurostar should be able to advise.

Comment: The issue here is that the onward train is an open access operator, not an ATOC service. So using the ticket on alternative services is not going to be possible. This situation is similar to having an unprotected connection between two separate plane tickets.
The OP will have to buy a new ticket for an alternative service.